# Why does this custom Ubuntu theme only affect some applications?

Tags: gnome, themes, gtk, window, numix

I took the [numix-gtk-theme](https://github.com/numixproject/numix-gtk-theme) from Github, and began modifying it to make my own custom theme.

One thing that I've noticed, is that the custom theme only affects some of the Ubuntu windows.  It seems that applications have their own window paneling, that I am unable to change.

For example:

Notice how `gedit` has the default Ubuntu buttons,
while the GNOME file manager is using my theme.

[image]

Is there a way I can get `gedit` and other applications to match my existing theme?  I want all the windows to look the same.

**Additional info:**

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, and have gone to the `gnome-flashback`. I'm also using the `gnome-tweak-tool` to apply the GTK+ theme.

It seems that I'm on GTK 3.0
(at least that's what I'm changing in the `numix` theme to see relevant changes).

Comment: It's possible you may be encountering issues with client-side decorations. Please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28650646/what-is-client-side-decoration. You could also raise an issue on the GitHub page if you feel the problem is at that end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need manually change Metacity theme with GSettings:
`gsettings set org.gnome.metacity theme THEME_NAME`

Comment: This fixed my problem!